# In standard Joomla 3 how to decide the length and perhps parts of a text of an article in Archive listing

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I am a beginner and should like to have certain length of archived articles to appear in search result.
Currently ~ 110 characters appear  at the user screen.

I looked over the different menus in this context without success.

It would be nice to decide the starting place of characters of the text to appear in the archive list screen.

[image: Layout setting]

Comment: Which template is used on front-end?

Comment: We are using the default layer - pls. look at my post. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understand the default layout, but in `bővítmények->sablonok` (`extensions->templates`) which template is used?

Comment: In this menu there are four templates listed. Pls. look at my post. Testing them the second one jd_paris gives result similar to the user's one. Thanks